# uses or overrides a deprecated API flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, localauthentication

today I linked my project to firebase all the latest versions and when running the emulator getting  Note: "uses or overrides a deprecated API." for firebase_auth, firebase_core, flutter_secure_storage, local_auth. What should I do about this?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/78137#issuecomment-970387592 (might be your case with `local_auth`)

Answer (score 1):

Those are warnings from the APIs the plugins are using. Your code should work just fine.

Comment: yaa code is working just fine for a time being but will it cause any problem in the future since its showing deprecated API

Comment: No, I don't think it will.

Comment: then why is this deprecated API every time I run in emulator

Comment: No, there's nothing to resolve as the warning is coming from the package itself. Checkout this issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50870